# onBlur not called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have made a react component for an input element.

In my application the user is able to create some rectangles. When you click on the rectangle a properties tab is shown. Within this properties tab I have included several of my input components.

When the user decided to edit f.e. the name of a rectangle. He clicks into the input change it and everything is done.

If the user clicks on the next rectangle `componenWillReceiveProps` is called within my input component.

So the problem is now with the `onBlur` event.

If the user changes the name and clicks on a different rectangle only `componenWillReceiveProps` is called and the onBlur event will be ignored.

Means that the typed value is gone and the name of the first rectangle stays the same.

**Input Component (TypeScript)**

```
export default class Input extends React.Component<InputProps, InputState> {

  static propTypes = {};

  static defaultProps = {
    type: 'text', readOnly: false, disabled: false
  };

  constructor(props: InputProps, context: any) {
    super(props, context);
    const value = props.value ? props.value : '';
    this.state = { id: props.id, value };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const id = this.props.id || generateId();
    this.setState(assign(this.state, { id: id }));
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: InputProps, nextContext: any): void {
    this.setState(assign(this.state, { value: nextProps.value }));
  }

  render() {
    const id = this.state.id + '_input';
    return (
      <div className='col-xs-6'>
        <div className="input-field gd-input">
          <input id={id} type={this.props.type} value={this.state.value}
                 onChange={this.onChange}
                 placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                 readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
                 disabled={this.props.disabled}/>
          <label htmlFor={id}>{this.props.label}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  onChange(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(assign(this.state, { value }));
  }

  handleBlur(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(assign(this.state, { value }));
    if (this.props.onBlur) {
      this.props.onBlur(value);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: can you show the code ? when you change the input element y `componentWillReceiveProps` is getting called, are u using these `input` elements in child component and passing the value from parent ?

Comment: @MayankShukla added the code for the component. When i change the value of an input a parent method is called and the input element gets new props

Comment: @MayankShukla updated the example / use case. Maybe it's easier now to understand the problem

Comment: It would be helpful to see the interfaces for InputProps and InputState, could you also add these to your example?